# Pegar apenas os dias do mes retirando o sabado e domingo com JAVASCRIPT/TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, typescript

Como consigo adicionar apenas os dias do mês em um array retirando sabado e domingo?

usuario vai informar o mês e o ano e com esse mês eu pego os dias.

ex:

Março 2018

1 2 5 6 7 8 9 12 13 14 15 16 19 20 21 22 23 26 27 28 29 30

Answer (score 2):

Sem o moment-js, porque... meter uma lib inteira só para isto até da dó:

```
function getWeekDaysInMonth(month = 0, year = 2018) {
  console.log('Weekdays for', new Date(year, month, 1).toString())
  return new Array(new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate()).fill().map((n, i) => {
    const weekDay = new Date(year, month, ++i).getDay();
    return weekDay > 0 && weekDay < 6 && i;
  }).filter(val => !!val);
}

console.log(getWeekDaysInMonth(2, 2018))
```

Outputs:
[ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ]

[Repl.it Session](https://repl.it/@moshmage/Get-Week-Days-from-Date-javascript)

Explicando:

Primeiro nós vamos ter que iterar pelo total de dias do mês que é providenciado, neste caso Marco (0 based, então 2) - este loop é feito construindo uma array de length igual ao maximo de dias do mês que depois é enchida com "nada" (via `fill()` e iterada pelo `map()`.

de seguida, temos que ver se o dia da semana dessa data é maior que 0 (domingo) ou 6 (sábado) e se sim, retornar *o dia do mês*.

assim que esse mapeamento acabar, nós vamos filtrar da array todos os valores que não são positivos.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente precisei recuperar todos os *Domingos*, as *Quintas* e os *Sábados* do mês atual para gerar uma escala. Encontrei o plugin [moment-weekdaysin](https://github.com/kodie/moment-weekdaysin) para a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Você deve executar o `moment` passando como parâmetro o ano e mês que o usuário informar: `moment('2018-03')`

Logo em seguida, deve executar o método `weekdaysInMonth` do plugin [moment-weekdaysin](https://github.com/kodie/moment-weekdaysin), informando um `array` com valores de *0* a *6*.

```
0 = Domingo
1 = Segunda
2 = Terça
3 = Quarta
4 = Quinta
5 = Sexta
6 = Sábado
```

Como você só quer de *Segunda* à *Sexta* ficara assim: `weekdaysInMonth([1,2,3,4,5])`

#### Exemplo funcionando.

```js
// Define o idioma
moment.locale('pt-br');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let mes = document.querySelector('#mes');
let ano = document.querySelector('#ano');
const getDaysOfMonth = () => {
  const datas = moment(`${ano.value}-${mes.value}`).weekdaysInMonth([1,2,3,4,5]);
  datas.forEach(data => console.log(data.format('L')));
};
btn.addEventListener('click', getDaysOfMonth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kodie/moment-weekdaysin/master/moment-weekdaysin.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="mes" placeholder="Mês" min="1" max="12" value="3">
<input type="number" id="ano" placeholder="Ano" min="1990" max="2050" value="2018">
<button id="btn">OK</button>
```